# Setting image data URI (base64) as canvas background

Tags: javascript, canvas, background-image, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js. I have a video on a page, I am converting it into an image using canvas element.
And using `canvas.toDataURL()` is giving me correct image of the video in a base64 from.

Now I want to add this image's data URI as a background image of same canvas. 
I am using this code to do this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  var f_img = new fabric.Image(img);

  canvas.setBackgroundImage(
    f_img, 
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
     height: canvas.height,
     width: canvas.width
    }
  );
};
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

But this code is not working. I have tried setting data URI directly as well:

```
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(
    canvas.toDataURL(), 
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
     height: canvas.height,
     width: canvas.width
    }
  );
```

When I run above code it just removes the image drawn on the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a crossorigin enabled video, or the video need to serve from same server.

***DEMO***

```js
var videoEl = document.getElementById('videoEl');
videoEl.play();
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({radius:50,fill:'green'}));

function takeSnap(){
 canvas.contextTop.drawImage(videoEl,0,0,400,400)
 canvas.setBackgroundImage(canvas.upperCanvasEl.toDataURL(),function(){
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
  canvas.clearContext(canvas.contextTop);
 })

}
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<video width="400" height= "400" id='videoEl' crossorigin='anonymous' loop>
  <source src="https://d8d913s460fub.cloudfront.net/videoserver/cat-test-video-320x240.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<br>
<button onclick='takeSnap()'>takeSnap</button>
<br>
<canvas id='c' width='400' height='400'></canvas>
```

Comment: You are my hero. I worked all day yesterday to try and do this. Thank you!